# EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized using Saltstack boto_vpc module

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, salt-stack, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to create a vpc using Saltstack and boto_vpc module. This is my state:

```
vpc_create:
      module.run:
        - name: boto_vpc.create
        - cidr_block: '10.0.0.0/24'
        - vpc_name: 'myVpc'
        - region: 'us-east-1'
        - key: 'ADJJDNEJFJGNFKFKFKIW'
        - keyid: 'SJDJNFNEJUWLLLCLCLENNRBFLGSLSLKEMFUHE'
```

**The keys that I'm using are correct** but I got this **error**:

```
[INFO    ] Running state [boto_vpc.create] at time 14:25:35.839797
[INFO    ] Executing state module.run for boto_vpc.create
[ERROR   ] EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>7cb74939-afda-4722-a31e-2855c5cbe16b</RequestID></Response>
[ERROR   ] {'ret': False}
[INFO    ] Completed state [boto_vpc.create] at time 14:25:35.882840
[DEBUG   ] File /var/cache/salt/minion/accumulator/49944656 does not exist, no need to cleanup.
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded highstate.output
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded nested.output
local:
----------
          ID: vpc_create
    Function: module.run
        Name: boto_vpc.create
      Result: False
     Comment: Module function boto_vpc.create executed
     Started: 14:25:35.839797
    Duration: 43.043 ms
     Changes:
              ----------
              ret:
                  False
```

**Saltstack version:**

```
Salt: 2015.5.0
         Python: 2.6.9 (unknown, Apr  1 2015, 18:16:00)
         Jinja2: 2.7.2
       M2Crypto: 0.21.1
 msgpack-python: 0.4.6
   msgpack-pure: Not Installed
       pycrypto: 2.6.1
        libnacl: Not Installed
         PyYAML: 3.10
          ioflo: Not Installed
          PyZMQ: 14.3.1
           RAET: Not Installed
            ZMQ: 3.2.5
           Mako: Not Installed
```

I tried with `aws ec2 create-vpc --cidr-block 10.0.0.0/16` and works fine!

Comment: Is ADJJDNEJFJGNFKFKFKIW actually a valid access key? Are these temporary credentials that maybe have expired?

Comment: @jarmod the Keys are correct. I'm using them in other part of the app and works fine. Also, I was able to create the vpc via aws-cli without any problem.

Comment: I suspect that you have misconfigured something and the wrong credentials are being sent. Double-check how you are supplying access key, secret key, and, if these are temporary credentials, session token. One way to do this might be to run boto with debugging (debug=2 in boto.cfg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From reading the [salt reference](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.boto_vpc.html), it looks like *keyid* represents the access key and *key* represents the secret key. Have you accidentally transposed them?

Comment: @relopezz Glad the problem is resolved. You should probably also rotate your keys. The reason for this is that you were previously passing the secret key in place of the access key and because the access key is not a sensitive piece of data (whereas the secret key is) it will almost certainly have been logged in cleartext in various places, for example CloudTrail.