# When I use python boto connect to aws ec2 , it show SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

I'm using Windows 10 OS.

I want to count the number of IP Address of AWS.

I use `python 2.7.14` and `boto 2.6.0`

I add a file which name is `boto.config` locate C:\Users\Administrator folder

The content of the boto.config is:

```
[Credentials]

aws_access_key_id=******

aws_secret_access_key=*****
```

The script is :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# -*- encoding: utf8 -*-

import boto.ec2

from pprint import pprint

import ssh

import requests

import urllib3

import certifi

import ssl

conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('cn-north-1')

reservations = conn.get_all_instances()

InstanceMap=[]

for reservation in reservations:

    for instance in reservation.instances:

        if 'env' in instance.tags and instance.tags['env'] == 'test':

            InstanceMap.append(instance.ip_address)

f = open('F:\ip.txt','w')

pprint(InstanceMap, f)
```

When I run this script, it show the error formation:

> SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:661)

What's the method can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Boto \[SSL: CERTIFICATE\_VERIFY\_FAILED\] certificate verify failed while connecting to S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115250/boto-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-while-connecting)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28115250/boto-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-while-connecting  .  My question is different.

Answer (score 5):

I was having same issue with `boto3` and `Python 3.7` on `Windows 10` machine. As it turned out, since I was using corporate device with Proxy installed, *.amazonaws.com certificate was getting replaced by the Proxy certificate. This Proxy certificate chain needed to be trusted by Python `certifi` module. Whether or not, you have a proxy, below method should resolve `SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED` error.

Here is what I did, to resolve the issue -

1. Find the path where cacert.pem is located -

> Install certifi, if you don't have. Command: `pip install certifi`

```
import certifi
certifi.where()
C:\\Users\\[UserID]\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\certifi\\cacert.pem
```

2. Set `AWS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable to the `cacert.pem` path -

   `AWS_CA_BUNDLE=C:\Users\[UserID]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\site-packages\certifi\cacert.pem`
3. Download the chain of certificates from amazonaws.com URL. For example: Go to https://sts.amazonaws.com/xyz on a browser and export Root, all the intermediate certificates, domain cert and save as base64 encoded .cer file. Open the certificates in notepad, copy all the contents.
4. Now open the cacert.pem in a notepad and just add every downloaded certificate contents (`---Begin Certificate--- *** ---End Certificate---`) at the end.

Restart the command line prompt or PowerShell, SSL verification error should be resolved.

> **Do not use** `is_secure = False` in your organization's envrionments. This is essentially disabling SSL verification.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `is_secure = False` like below, in order to skip ssl verification,

```
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('cn-north-1',is_secure=False)
```

Try providing the credentials as so, that way you would know if the keys in boto config are old if this works, and if this returns the same issue then you need to check your api-key and secret on [aws](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/wheres-my-secret-access-key/).

```
API_KEY = 'Actual API_KEY'
API_SECRET = 'Actual Secret'
conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('us-east-2',aws_access_key_id=API_KEY,aws_secret_access_key=API_SECRET,is_secure=False)
```

Comment: When I adding "is_secure = False", the error show :                      
  conn = boto.ec2.connect_to_region('cn-north-1',is_secure=False)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\boto-2.6.0-
EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response><Errors><Error><Code>AuthFailure</Code><Message>AWS was not able to validate the provided access credentials</Message></Error></Errors><RequestID>****************************</RequestID></Response>

Comment: Hi @Andrew I have edited the answer to help you validate your keys. hope it helps

Comment: Omi Harjani, thanks very much, this returns the same issue . I will check my api-key

Comment: Omi Harjani, I check my api-key and secret . It's right .    Does this need to allow my access_key_id and secret_id corresponding users to give the appropriate permissions? At present, this account is the authority of the administrator .

Comment: Maybe this is the reason:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648236/ec2responseerror-401-unauthorized-using-saltstack-boto-vpc-module

Comment: @Andrew Make sure the time on your machine is set correctly.

People have faced the same issue when the time on the server and your local machine are not in sync.

Comment: @Andrew Yup if you switch your api key and secret that could be the reason too :)

Comment: Omi Harjani, The time zone of My EC2 instance is UTC.   The python script is run in the bastion server(it is EC2 instance too) which can ssh Login  these ec2  instance. The time zone of bastion server  is  UTC .  My script is want to get  ec2 ip information from the url https://console.amazonaws.cn/ec2 , the Availability Zone is cn-north-1, the time zone is UTC+8 . How can I set the time in which server can solve the problem: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized

Comment: I solve this problem. The reason of this problem : EC2ResponseError: EC2ResponseError: 401 Unauthorized . It's the role of IAM  has not  Sufficient  authority. I change another IAM role ,it's OK now.

Comment: According to this article :  https://github.com/boto/boto/issues/2885  ,  I degrade the boto from  2.6.0  to  2.32.1.   It' s  OK

Comment: Omi Harjani , thank you very much.  Your advice helped me a lot

Comment: @Andrew I was using boto v 2.48.0 on which the same code worked like a breeze. I guess that's why I just couldn't replicate the same error on my local. Great that you finally solved it :)